# How to add new property to a Realm Object?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I am trying to add a new property to the Realm object UserDetails. Here is my try:

```
class CustomerDetails: Object {
   dynamic var customer_id = 0
   dynamic var customer_name = ""
}
```

Now i need to add a new property "company_name" to the object UserDetails which is already being created earlier. How to add a new one to the existing Realm object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

1. Just delete your app from simulator and run it again. Everytime you change properties on your Realm objects your existing database becomes incompatible to the new one.
   As long as you are still in the developing stage you can simply delete the app from the simulator / device and start it again.
2. Write this code in AppDelegate's disFinishLaunchWithOptions method:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
     schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
        }
})

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
let realm = try! Realm()
```

I suggest you to follow the second one.

Answer (score 6):

You just add the property to the Realm model, but will have to provide a [migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) in order to update the stored data to the new format.

This includes setting a `schemaVersion` in your `Realm.Configuration` which tells Realm that the schema was changed, and providing a `migrationBlock` which initializes the new property for existing objects (probably just by setting an empty string). On the next start of the app, Realm will automatically run the migration and thereby update the stored data to the new schema.

Answer (score 0):

✅ This works for me.

Each time you **add** or **remove** properties, upgrade the schema version (+1). Realm itself migrates.

```
func migrateRealm() {
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 5)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    migrateRealm()
    return true
}
```